# Pegar apenas alguns atributos de tags HTML

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

Tenho vários `inputs`, vindo de um `curl`, mas eu preciso apenas do `name` e do `value` desses inputs:

```html
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="timezone" value="180" id="u_0_9">
```

Eu tenho esse código:

```php
preg_match_all('/name="(.*?)" value="(.*?)"/is', $response, $names);
```

Só que esse código me traz registros errados, às vezes o que preciso ele não me mostra, quero apenas nome e valor.

Lembrando nem todos os inputs estão assim, tem alguns que estão assim:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="jazoest" value="2703" autocomplete="off">
```

Não possui `id`, ou outros atributos, mas o que eu quero é só nome e valor.

Alguma dica?

Comment: O que significa `registros errados`, tens um exemplo? Me parece que com os dois exemplos que tu deu está pegando: https://regex101.com/r/c0IvzV/1

Comment: e o teste do código também pega: https://gist.github.com/ogabrielsantos/f020c1728d8fd9b06aefa8797e5d8ab2

Comment: @GabrielSantos, sim ele estava pegando outras coisas além dos inputs, eu resolvi usando `array_combine`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você mencionou o `curl`, estou assumindo que você tem uma string contendo todo o HTML. Nesse caso, uma alternativa é usar a [extensão DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```php
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
<body>
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="timezone" value="180" id="u_0_9">
<input type="hidden" name="jazoest"
 autocomplete="off" value="2703">
<input type="radio" value="value" name="test" >
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
// obter todos os elementos input
$inputs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    // obter o name e value
    echo $input->getAttribute('name'). '='. $input->getAttribute('value'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

A saída é:

> timezone=180
> jazoest=2703
> test=value

Se quiser, você pode restringir o tipo de `input` fazendo algo como:

```php
if ($input->getAttribute('type') == 'hidden') {
    // só pega os valores se o campo for type=hidden
}
```

Assim, você só pega os campos `hidden`, por exemplo. Outra alternativa para restringir a busca é usar [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php):

```php
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// obter somente input com type="hidden"
$entries = $xpath->query('//input[@type = "hidden"]');
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo $entry->getAttribute('name'). '='. $entry->getAttribute('value'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Neste caso, ele só busca por `input`'s que possuem o `type="hidden"`. A saída é:

> timezone=180
> jazoest=2703

---

#### Usando regex

A solução acima eu acho mais simples do que usar regex. Não que seja "errado" usar regex, só acho que neste caso eu acho mais adequado usar um parser de HTML (seja o `DOMDocument`, seja qualquer outro [desta lista](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)), já que ele consegue lidar com várias situações que são bem mais difíceis de tratar com regex.

Por exemplo, a regex que você usou: `name="(.*?)" value="(.*?)"`. Ela só vai pegar o `name` e `value` se eles estiverem **exatamente nesta ordem** e com um espaço separando-os.

No teste que fiz acima, repare que eu propositalmente coloquei o atributo `autocomplete` entre o `name` e `value` no segundo `input` (e ainda coloquei uma quebra de linha no meio da tag, o que é permitido em HTML), e no terceiro `input` eu inverti e coloquei o `value` antes do `name`. Então esta regex só pegaria o primeiro `input`.

Claro que daria para arrumar isso em uma única regex gigante, mas há detalhes demais para se preocupar, caso queira uma expressão que considere todos os casos possíveis. Por exemplo, para ler as 3 tags que coloquei no exemplo anterior, pegando o `name` e `value`, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```php
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
<body>
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="timezone" value="180" id="u_0_9">
<input type="hidden" name="jazoest"
 autocomplete="off" value="2703">
<input type="radio" value="value" name="test" >
</body>
</html>
HTML;
$pos = 0;
// procura por uma tag input
while (preg_match('/<input\b([^>]*)>/i', $html, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $pos)) {
    $conteudo = $match[1][0]; // conteúdo da tag input atual
    $pos_conteudo = 0;
    $type = '';
    $name = '';
    $value = '';
    // busca os atributos da tag input atual
    while ($pos_conteudo < strlen($conteudo) &&
           preg_match('/\b(type|name|value)\s*=\s*(?|"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\'|([^\'">\s]*))/i',
                      $conteudo, $match_conteudo, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $pos_conteudo)) {
        $attr_name = strtolower($match_conteudo[1][0]);
        if ($attr_name == 'type') {
            $type = $match_conteudo[2][0];
        } else if ($attr_name == 'name') {
            $name = $match_conteudo[2][0];
        } else if ($attr_name == 'value') {
            $value = $match_conteudo[2][0];
        }
        // continua buscando os atributos de onde parou o anterior
        $pos_conteudo = strlen($attr_name) + $match_conteudo[1][1];
    }
    // a próxima chamada de preg_match começa depois do conteúdo já encontrado
    $pos = strlen($conteudo) + $match[1][1];
    echo $type. '='. $name. '='.$value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

A saída é:

> hidden=timezone=180
> hidden=jazoest=2703
> radio=test=value

Novamente, você pode fazer `if ($type == 'hidden')` ou algo do tipo se quiser restringir algum tipo de `input` específico (ou mudar na própria regex acima, se quiser).

Basicamente, esta solução se aproveita do fato de [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) poder receber como parâmetro a posição na qual começará a busca. E usando a opção `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`, a posição em que o *match* é encontrado também é retornada no array de *matches* (assim eu consigo saber onde a tag foi encontrada, e posso continuar a busca a partir dali).

Note que eu não uso muito `.*?`, já que o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere (e como você usou a opção `s`, isso faz com que o ponto também considere as quebras de linha). Apesar de `.*?` parecer uma solução simples e que "funciona", [ela tem o seu preço](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_expensive).

Basicamente, como `.*` corresponde a quaisquer caracteres, ele pode ir além da tag atual (por exemplo, [se alguma tag tiver `name` mas não tiver `value`](https://regex101.com/r/ex5Cge/1/)). Ex:

```php
$html = <<<HTML
<input type="hidden" name="semvalue">
<input type="hidden" value="abc">
HTML;

if (preg_match_all('/name="(.*?)" value="(.*?)"/is', $html, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Com a opção `s`, o ponto considera quebras de linha. Com isso, a regex procura por `name="` e em seguida vai procurando por todos os caracteres da string (incluindo quebras de linha), até encontrar `" value="`. Por isso ela acaba "invadindo" outra tag, e o resultado é:

```php
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(49) "name="semvalue">
<input type="hidden" value="abc""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(30) "semvalue">
<input type="hidden"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "abc"
  }
}
```

Outra coisa que o `.*?` pode fazer é ficar indo e voltando na string, verificando todas as possibilidades, tornando a regex mais ineficiente, principalmente quando você está em um trecho que não corresponde à expressão. Já usando `[^"]`, pelo menos você garante que a regex vai parar quando encontrar o caractere `"`, o que já diminui bastante essa ineficiência, aleḿ de garantir que ela não vai "invadir" outras tags.

Esse é um detalhe importante: em regex é muito melhor quando você [diz exatamente o que quer e o que não quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want). No caso, eu não quero "qualquer coisa" (`.*`). Dentro de uma tag, por exemplo, o que eu quero na verdade é "qualquer coisa que não seja o fechamento da tag". Ou seja, qualquer caractere que não seja o `>`. Por isso eu usei:

```
<input\b([^>]*)>
```

O trecho `[^>]*` significa "zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam o `>`". Tudo que está entre `[^` e `]` é uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), ou seja, tudo que for diferente do que está lá dentro. Como lá dentro só tem o `>`, então este trecho pega tudo que não for o fechamento da tag. Isso considera inclusive as quebras de linha, o que torna a opção `s` desnecessária. Mas ainda mantive a opção `i`, pois tags são *case insensitive* (ou seja, a regex pega tanto `input` quanto `INPUT`).

E como este trecho está entre parênteses, isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que eu posso recuperar com `$match[1][0]`. O `$match[1]` refere-se ao primeiro grupo de captura (já que é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex), e `$match[1][0]` contém a string que foi capturada pela regex. Já `$match[1][1]` contém a posição em que este *match* foi encontrado (esta informação só está disponível quando você passa a opção `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`).

De qualquer forma, esta primeira regex serve para pegar todo o conteúdo de uma tag `input`. Depois eu uso **outra** regex para buscar os atributos da tag atual, por isso eu uso o conteúdo da tag encontrada, em vez do HTML inteiro. Isso restringe o espaço de busca e evita que a regex sem querer comece a olhar em outras tags (o que pode acontecer dependendo do caso, se eu usar `.*`, por exemplo).

O trecho `(type|name|value)` busca pela string "type", **ou** "name", **ou** "value" (o caractere `|` [significa **ou**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)), e está dentro de parênteses para formar um grupo de captura, assim eu consigo obter a string que foi capturada. Em seguida temos zero ou mais espaços (`\s*`), sinal de igual, zero ou mais espaços, e depois temos 3 opções:

- uma string delimitada por aspas duplas: `"([^"]*)"` **ou**
- uma string delimitada por aspas simples: `\'([^\']*)\'` (pois é permitido ter `name='nome'`) **ou**
- zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam aspas simples, aspas duplas ou espaços
  `([^\'">\s]*)` (já que podemos ter coisas como `required` ou `name=nome`)

Repare que os conteúdos também estão entre parênteses, o que forma outro grupo de captura. No caso dos valores entre aspas, eu deixei as próprias aspas fora do grupo de captura, assim eu garanto que só terei o valor de cada atributo.

Como há mais de uma possibilidade (entre aspas duplas, aspas simples ou sem
aspas), eu uso o `(?|`, que indica um [*branch reset*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html), ou seja, o que for capturado será o grupo 2 (caso contrário, um seria o grupo 2, o outro seria o 3, etc, e eu teria que verificar qual está vazio e qual não está para saber qual foi capturado - com o *branch reset*, basta verificar o grupo 2).

Depois eu verifico qual o nome do atributo que foi capturado (`type`, `name` ou `value`) e pego o respectivo valor. Atualizo a posição para o próximo `preg_match` e continuo o *loop*, procurando pelo próximo atributo da tag. Quando o conteúdo da tag termina, eu imprimo o `type`, `name` e `value` encontrados (e eles estarão vazios caso não tenha sido encontrado) e volto para o `while` externo, que continua procurando pelo próximo `input`.

---

Até seria possível fazer uma única regex que reconhece ao mesmo tempo uma tag `input` e os seus respectivos atributos `type`, `name` e `value`, em qualquer ordem. Mas ficaria grande demais (seria uma junção das duas regex acima com mais algumas alternâncias para garantir que os atributos possam estar em qualquer ordem), mas sinceramente, ficaria complexa demais e na minha opinião já não começa a valer a pena.

---

Como você pode ver, é bem mais fácil usar um *parser* de HTML. A sua regex pode até funcionar para casos mais simples, mas complique um pouquinho o HTML e a complexidade da regex vai aumentando gradativamente, até se tornar impraticável.

Por exemplo, se tivermos `value="<abc>"`, a regex do primeiro `while` já não funciona, pois ela pega tudo entre o `<input` e o primeiro `>` que encontrar. Aí teríamos que verificar se o `>` não está entre aspas, para ter certeza que ele é o fechamento da tag.

Outro caso é quando tem uma tag dentro de comentários:

```html
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="test2" value="ops"> -->
```

A regex acima pega esta tag também, pois não colocamos a verificação para saber se ela está dentro de um comentário. Só lembrando que o comentário pode se estender por várias linhas e ter várias outras tags e conteúdos dentro dele, então verificar isso com uma regex não é nada trivial.

Já o parser de HTML cuida de todos esses casos especiais para você. A solução com `DOMDocument`, por exemplo, obtém corretamente os valores que têm `>` e ignora os comentários, sem precisar de nenhuma alteração no código. Então avalie se a regex é de fato a melhor solução para o seu caso. Pois quando se trata de *parsing* de HTML, [nem sempre é](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).