# Ignorar alguns campos com regex

Tags: php, regex, libcurl, preg-match

No PHP estou usando `preg_match_all` para pegar alguns dados desse formulário:

```
<form id="login_form" action="/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&amp;lwv=100" method="post" onsubmit="">
   <input type="hidden" name="jazoest" value="2653" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" name="lsd" value="AVq7w05r" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="error_box">
   <div id="loginform">
      <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="display" name="display" value=""><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="enable_profile_selector" name="enable_profile_selector" value="">
      <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="isprivate" name="isprivate" value="">
      <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="legacy_return" name="legacy_return" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="profile_selector_ids" name="profile_selector_ids" value="">
      <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="return_session" name="return_session" value="">
      <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="skip_api_login" name="skip_api_login" value="">
      <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="signed_next" name="signed_next" value="">
      <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="trynum" name="trynum" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="timezone" value="180" id="u_0_9">
      <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="lgndim" value="eyJ3IjoxOTIwLCJoIjoxMDgwLCJhdyI6MTkyMCwiYWgiOjEwNDAsImMiOjI0fQ==" id="u_0_a"><input type="hidden" name="lgnrnd" value="062429_kygL">
      <input type="hidden" id="lgnjs" name="lgnjs" value="1554816269">
      <div class="clearfix _5466 _44mg" id="email_container">
         <input type="text" class="inputtext _55r1 inputtext _1kbt inputtext _1kbt" name="email" id="email" tabindex="0" placeholder="Email ou telefone" value="" autofocus="1" aria-label="Email ou telefone">
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix _5466 _44mg">
         <input type="password" class="inputtext _55r1 inputtext _1kbt inputtext _1kbt" name="pass" id="pass" tabindex="0" placeholder="Senha" aria-label="Senha">
      </div>
      <div class="_xkt">
         <button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 _52e0 _4jy6 _4jy1 selected _51sy" id="loginbutton" name="login" tabindex="0" type="submit">Entrar</button>
      </div>
      <div id="login_link">
         <div class="_xkt"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate/?ars=facebook_login" id="forgot-password-link" target="">Esqueceu a conta?</a></div>
         <div class="_1rf5"><span class="_1rf8">ou</span></div>
         <div class="_xkt"><a role="button" class="_42ft _4jy0 _4jy6 _4jy2 selected _51sy" href="/r.php?locale=pt_BR&amp;display=page" style="font-size: 14px">Criar nova conta</a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="prefill_contact_point" name="prefill_contact_point" value="guizoio.188@gmail.com"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="prefill_source" name="prefill_source" value="browser_dropdown"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="prefill_type" name="prefill_type" value="password"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="first_prefill_source" name="first_prefill_source" value="browser_dropdown"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="first_prefill_type" name="first_prefill_type" value="contact_point"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="had_cp_prefilled" name="had_cp_prefilled" value="true"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="had_password_prefilled" name="had_password_prefilled" value="true"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="ab_test_data" value="">
</form>
```

Acontece que quando eu combino meus `arrays` aparece um botão

```
ou
Criar nova conta
Esqueceu a conta?
```

Segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu só preciso disso:

```
  public 'jazoest' => string '2729' (length=4)
  public 'lsd' => string 'AVqQhOsV' (length=8)
  public 'display' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'enable_profile_selector' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'isprivate' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'legacy_return' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'profile_selector_ids' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'return_session' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'skip_api_login' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'signed_next' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'trynum' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'timezone' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'lgndim' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'lgnrnd' => string '063516__LZq' (length=11)
  public 'lgnjs' => string 'n' (length=1)
```

Os dois últimos objetos como `email` e `pass` não preciso.

Meu código está assim:

```
public function getInputs()
    {
        $options = [
            CURLOPT_URL                         => $this->url['login'],
            CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $this->ua
        ];

        $request = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($request, $options);

        $response = curl_exec($request);

        curl_close($request);

        preg_match_all('/name="(.*?)" value="(.*?)"/', $response, $inputs);

        return (object) array_combine($inputs[1], $inputs[2]);
    }
```

Comment: Acho mais simples usar `DOMDocument`, como já sugeri na sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/373962/112052). Ou então vc percorre o array resultante (o resultado de `array_combine`) e remove os elementos que não precisa. Usar regex (como já expliquei na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/374027/112052)) nem sempre é a melhor solução para manipular HTML :-)

Comment: Sim, mas estou familiarizado com o cURL. :(

Comment: Mas no fim o `$response` terá uma string com o HTML - e se usar `CURLOPT_HEADER => false`, ela terá apenas o HTML, sem os headers, que vc pode passar diretamente para `DOMDocument::loadHTML` sem problemas..

Comment: Entendi agora, eu desativei o curl header, e consegui. deveriam traduzir a documentação do curl :(

Comment: Até existe documentação em português, mas nem tudo está 100% bem traduzido. A [página do `curl_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-exec.php), por exemplo, só tem uma pequena parte em português e o resto em inglês :-(

Comment: Oloco.... eu nem sabia que tinha a documentação no site do php.net, eu olhava por aqui https://curl.haxx.se/... mas vlw irmao