# Php 7.1, Como fazer uma REGEX do seguinte padrão:<div class='inline-render' data-type='credit-card' data-listing-id='1234'>?

Tags: php, regex

Tenho uma texto onde o seguinte padrão pode se repetir muitas ou nenhuma vez e com diferentes valores de `data-type`:

```
<div class='inline-render' data-type='ALGUM TIPO' data-listing-id='VALOR'>
```

Eu preciso recuperar todos os VALORES do `id` quando o tipo é `credit-card`.

Exemplo:
No grante texto abaixo tenho duas ocorrências de 'credit-card' que são as seguintes:

```
<div class='inline-render' data-type='credit-card' data-listing-id='1234'>
e
<div class='inline-render' data-type='credit-card' data-listing-id='1111'>
```

No exemplo abaixo eu teria que repuperar 1234 e 1111.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lobortis purus sapien, at vulputate magna condimentum a. Phasellus massa sem, ullamcorper ut pellentesque eu, pulvinar sit amet risus. Suspendisse placerat odio sapien, ac efficitur purus congue a. Nunc nunc metus, convallis <div class='inline-render' data-type='credit-card' data-listing-id='1234'> sed leo at, fringilla lacinia nibh. Nullam imperdiet facilisis efficitur. Maecenas venenatis nunc sit amet nibh facilisis euismod. Vivamus sed <div class='inline-render' data-type='credit-card' data-listing-id='1111'>lacinia odio. Nunc et purus sit amet felis tempus fermentum finibus tempor mi. Phasellus at nibh nec mi laoreet lobortis. Quisque eget dui quis purus fermentum mollis.

Sed mauris est, congue eget tortor sed, efficitur cursus augue. Curabitur rutrum erat diam, non egestas leo accumsan sit amet. Nunc varius ante metus, <div class='inline-render' data-type='nota' data-listing-id='1111'>congue luctus sapien ullamcorper nec. Nullam eu hendrerit odio, placerat ultrices libero. Proin fringilla orci et magna eleifend, eget tincidunt ex ultricies. Quisque <div class='inline-render' data-type='roupa' data-listing-id='1234'>eget imperdiet mauris. Cras purus felis, aliquet quis vulputate vitae, aliquet nec lectus. Cras at purus eget ex posuere faucibus. Duis rhoncus feugiat pellentesque. Pellentesque vitae felis et metus convallis sagittis eu in arcu.
```

### UPDATE

Eu fiz a seginte solução, dado que o nome do data-type tem que constar na REGEX:

```
preg_match_all ("/data-type='credit-card' data-listing-id='(.*?)'/U", $data['html'], $pat_array);
dd($pat_array);
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    0 => "data-type='credit-card' data-listing-id='1234'"
    1 => "data-type='credit-card' data-listing-id='1111'"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    0 => "1234"
    1 => "1111"
  ]
]
```

Eu só não estou satisfeito é com o espaço em branco entre `-card' dat` pois pode variar e a REGEX não recuperar.

Comment: Sem tempo pra escrever uma resposta agora, mas talvez isso te ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/373962/112052

Comment: Ajuda bastante. Mas não é só recueorar atributos, tem uma condicão. Só pode ser quando o data-type for credit-card. Então acho que a palavra creditcar tem que entrar na regex. Eu vou atualizar o que já consegui até agora.

Comment: Na resposta que tem lá, tem um código que usa regex, e dá pra pegar os atributos e respectivos valores. Se der tempo eu escrevo uma resposta, mas a princípio acho que dá pra adaptar aquele código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
\data-type='credit-card'(\s?)data-listing-id='(.*?)'\U
```

Testado em: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/rHE